# Theme.AppCompat.DayNight doesn't work on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

In my app, I've tried to change theme (light/dark) with `uiModeManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`.
**It works perfectly on my Nexus 5 with Android 6** and on an emulator with Android 6, but it doesn't work on emulator with Android 5.1.
Why?

I've also tried with `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` but on Android 6 it change only the menu theme (?) and on Android 5 doesn't work anyway..

I don't think that is a problem of theme, but this is my code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In my tests, I found out that it works for Release builds, but not for debug builds. Maybe it's a bit buggy.

Comment: Mh.. No.. I've signed and create the release apk, but doesn't work on Lollipop.. You use `uiModeManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`?

Comment: I use this, based on my shared preference value (this is in my Application onCreate method): AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(theme == Constants.THEME_LIGHT ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO : theme == Constants.THEME_DARK ?
                AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);

Comment: Thanks!!! With `AppCompactDelegate` it works also the debug release!

Comment: Glad to know it, posted it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

in your Application's onCreate method.